# Wicket: block cookie usage until confirmed by user

Tags: cookies, wicket

According to a European Union law, websites must not use cookies until confirmed by the user. How can we tell Wicket to not automatically use cookies until the user has confirmed it? Is there some add-on already available for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can create an own `Filter` instance that is invoked before `WicketFilter` and pass a `ServletResponse` instance to the chain that prevents cookie creation:

```
chain.doFilter(req, new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
    @Override
    public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [cookiecuttr](http://cookiecuttr.com/) and have wicket look for the cookie it sets before setting any of it's own.